# Is there a way to store objects in a mySQL database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, object, orm

I have a database using MySQL called "users". 
In it are two tables. "first" and "second".

I take the users information from a form using JavaScript
as an array of objects.

e.g. `let usersInformation = [{"name":"james", "age":"30"}]`

How can I easily store each array of objects?

In the past I have created columns e.g. "name"  and then stored the value of "name" in that column.

Is there a way to store objects in a MySQL database. 
I looked up the term ORM and thought that may be of help.

Comment: MySQL supports [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html). Use...

Answer (score 5):

You can use the JSON data type of MySQL.

```sh
mysql> create database user; 

mysql> use user
# Create a table with a json data type
mysql> create table user (json JSON); 

# Insert an array into the field
mysql> insert into user(json) values ('["first", "second", "third", "4th"]'); 

# Insert an object
mysql> insert into user(json) values('{"name": "Levi", "last": "Jr"}');

mysql> select * from user;
+-------------------------------------+
| json                                |
+-------------------------------------+
| ["first", "second", "third", "4th"] |
| {"last": "Jr", "name": "Levi"}      |
+-------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can use the `JSON_EXTRACT` to get some info from the field and filter it in the WHERE clause.

Here is how to use it: `JSON_EXTRACT([field], [expression]))`, [expression] being how you going to extract the info from the field.

Ex.:

```sh
mysql> select * from user where JSON_EXTRACT(user.json, '$.name') = 'Levi';
+--------------------------------+
| json                           |
+--------------------------------+
| {"last": "Jr", "name": "Levi"} |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from user where JSON_EXTRACT(user.json, '$[0]') = 'first';
+-------------------------------------+
| json                                |
+-------------------------------------+
| ["first", "second", "third", "4th"] |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Before send your object to the query convert it to `json`. If you need you can make your table field as `MEDIUM TEXT`

```
let usersInformation = [{"name":"james", "age":"30"}];
usersInformation = JSON.stringify(usersInformation);
```

Then send this to your query.

Answer (score 0):

**use JSON.stringify() & JSON.parse()**

**object to text**

> const obj = {name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York"}; const myJSON =
> JSON.stringify(obj);

```
*JSON can be store in the db with text datatype.*
```

**text to object**

> const txt = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}' const obj =
> JSON.parse(txt);

```
*text can be taken from the db and pass as object with use of JSON.parse()*
```